# why wont this work? - Getting a window that is hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, window, find

Within my application, i use the hidden and visible porperties to make windows how or not show to the user.
Now at some point, when i am in Window1, i want to make a check if there is still a instance of the main window, that is hidden.
Googling, i found (also on SO) that i need to use this code:

```
Window deze = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().Where(x => x.Name == "MainWindow").FirstOrDefault();
```

But whatever i fill in for the part `OfType<MainWindow>` or for the `"MainWindow"` it keeps returning null, even when im 100% sure there must be 1 instance.

Checking in the code of the main window, that is called in the solution explorer (visual express) "mainWindow.xaml"
i see that the code looks like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {      
        //creating the exitmessage for use later on, after all, we want to use this in an other method.


        public MainWindow()
        {
......
        }
```

I really have no clue at all, why that "Window deze"  keeps returning null when im 100% sure there is a hidden instance of the main window.

Anyone got an idea on this one ?
Im i just totally overlooking some logical solution ?

thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` is redundant, as you see it checks for a specific name, which does not concern you.

Comment: Yes. And the Name is distinct from the Window's class name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Window deze = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
```

What you are doing is looking at a property of the window called name and seeing if it matches the string "MainWindow".  It does not.  Since you are already looking for this type (of which there is only one), you just need to return the first one back to your variable.